# Review Audit picked a question that was improved after it was closed, rendering the audit faulty

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14621726). I'm not sure if this link will work for everyone, so [here is the link to the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731083/java-8-how-to-do-nested-split-using-stream).

I voted for "Leave open", but the system said I should have closed it. However, I believe this audit was generated automatically, and is not correct. The reason it is not correct is that the OP improved the question after it got closed. The improved question seemed valid enough to remain open, whereas the question before the improvement was clearly a question that had to be closed.

I believe the audit system picked an invalid question to test me, because the question was **edited after it was closed**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For posterity, let's describe in *broad* terms what the question is.

> How do I do X with Y method(s) in Java?
>
> `Code block which doesn't include attempt to use Y method(s)`
>
> Current output

One may think this rises to the occasion of "unclear" or "needs more details", but the OP *does* state in the comments:

> I've specified the output as well, i would appreciate if this code can be refactored using Stream.

With the above, and given even *without* the comment that they simply want their code rewritten with Streams, this makes the question *too broad*.  The edit didn't fix the broadness of scope; they have working, valid code and they want us to refactor it using the Stream API without them having used the Stream API.

The audit was correct on this one.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced yet: "too broad" has this description: "*There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*" I don't see how this valid question that just doesn't show effort falls under this.

Answer (score 2):

No. That question is still crap. The poster hasn't specified what output they're expecting. It should rightfully stay closed until the OP makes it acceptable.

Comment: You're right for the wrong reasons.  The OP does tacitly state their expected output, but they don't show any attempt at what they've tried, or where they've failed.

Comment: @Makoto indeed if you carefully read question and *all comments* you can see that "output is" should be read as "Output I expect is:" and absolutely not "code shown above produces following output ..." I don't think that reading all comments should be necessary to understand the question so I believe "poster hasn't specified what output they are expecting" is perfectly valid for current state of *the question*.

Comment: What I'm saying is, there are *other*, more pressing things to look at in this question to justify its closure.  The fact that they mention streams at all and the fact that their code contains *nothing* related to streams implies that they want us to do the work for them.  That's enough in my mind to close it.  Comments do add some valuable context; although it should've been edited into the question, they comments *are* available in the review.

Comment: @Makoto Makes sense... I've read your comment as "lack of specified output is *not valid reason* to keep it closed" while I probably should have read "there are *also other* more important issues to keep it closed". To me one even not the most important reason is enough to "keep closed" -  so if on first glance it does not look like valid question I'd keep it closed without digging into more reasons.